# What kinds of processes do orthostochastic matrices represent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, orthogonal-matrices

An [orthostochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthostochastic_matrix) is a [bistochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix) $B$ such that $B_{ij}\equiv O_{ij}^2$ for some orthogonal matrix $O$.

Bistochastic matrices can be given a direct interpretation as describing stochastic processes: they describe how (specific types of) stochastic processes act on probability vectors.

Is there any intuition or more general understanding of the types of stochastic processes described by a bistochastic matrix that is also orthostochastic?

Comment: One fact that comes to mind (from the proof of the [Schur Horn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Horn_theorem)) is that $\operatorname{diag}(U^*\operatorname{diag}(v)U) = |U|^2 v$